# Plotly line graph legend to not include fill colour

Tags: r, plotly

I have a legend on a plotly filled line graph below that looks like this:

[image]

Is there anything I can add to the legend layout section of the code so that the legend only includes the line colour, but not the fill colour?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this soemthing that is not covered by the [plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/r/legend/) ?

Comment: No, I've looked and it doesn't appear to be there (which is why I am asking here!)

Answer (score 0):

- using this as concept https://community.plotly.com/t/it-is-possible-to-fill-area-with-different-colors-on-a-line-plot/31664
- create traces with fill, `legendvisible=False`
- create traces that are just lines
- legend is as you require, just the line

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
df = pd.DataFrame({c:np.random.uniform(1,5,10) for c in ["First","Second","Third"]})

px.line(df, y=df.columns).update_traces(showlegend=False, fill="tozeroy").add_traces(px.line(df, y=df.columns).data)
```

[image]